# Plotting an interactive line graph with a moving window - looking for advice

Tags: python, matlab, plot, line, interactive

Hi so basically I plan to plot some data like this:

```
Variable  |  Hour 1  |  Hour 2  |  Hour 3
x         |  80      |  60      |  90
y         |  45      |  50      |  20
z         |  65      |  65      |  35
```

Basically I'm expecting a line graph with a point marked each hour for each variable. Then from here I need to be able to draw a window (rectangle) over the graph, selecting a small region of the graph. This window will then thicken the complete line for any line which runs through the window i.e. between the threshold on the y-axis.

Here is a quick image I made of the idea:

[image]

So I haven't started coding yet and this seems like a simple idea but basically I wanted some advice from those of you who are more experienced. I do know C/C++/Python/Matlab, and I was thinking Matlab would be the most simple solution, however Python is my preferred language as it is quick and more simple (using the Matplotlib library perhaps), also my other code is in Python.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're comfortable with Python already then to me it's a no brainer, go for Python. Unless you'll be coding with Maltab guru's who have never used Python.

Answer (score 1):

That should be pretty easy in both matlab and python/matplotlib. A matlab solution would look something like this (untested):

```
%assume x and y data are in cell arrays, so they can be of different lengths

line_handles = plot(x{1}, y{1}, x{2}, y{2}, x{3}, y{3});

rect = getrect; %select rectangle with mouse

for i = 1:length(line_handles)
    if your_intersection_test(rect, x{i}, y{i})
        set(line_handles(i), 'linewidth', 5)
    end
end
```

where I leave it to you to figure out how to test if a line crosses a rectangle (googling for 'test if line intersects rectangle' gives some useful results, but in your case it is a poly-line). A python solution should be almost similar,`matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector` might be useful for getting the rectangle with the mouse, but I have never used that. The rest of the code should translate almost 1 to 1 from matlab to python.